# How to edit a tag entry for the razor does not generate the attribute id - Asp.net Core MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Razor renders the input tag by creating an html with the attributes "id", "name" and others in a predefined way, but I need to discard the "id" attribute and leave the other attributes. This needs to be done with the input, select, and textArea tags or, if possible, with all tags that generate the id attribute in html. Does anyone know how to help me?

Before Rendering:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="CodigoControle" class="form-control input" placeholder=""></input>
```

After Rendering:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input" placeholder="" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="O campo Código de Controle deve ter no máximo 15 caracteres" data-val-maxlength-max="15" id="PaisViewModel_CodigoControle" maxlength="15" name="PaisViewModel.CodigoControle" value="">
```

Result I need (without the id attribute):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input" placeholder="" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="O campo Código de Controle deve ter no máximo 15 caracteres" data-val-maxlength-max="15" maxlength="15" name="PaisViewModel.CodigoControle" value="">
```

Customization class:

```
public class CustomTagHelper : TagHelper
{        
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {

        //var attributeObjects = context.AllAttributes.ToList();
        //output.TagName = "input";
        //output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
        
        //Remover o atributo id??????
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove the id attribute?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos I need to remove the ids attributes because I will use only the name attributes of the fields. I'm working with windows modals bootstrap and if I open two windows with the same viewmodel gives conflict in the ids...  If I remove the ids, I can manipulate the fields using jequery with only the name or a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tag helper should remove the generated id attribute from `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = ForAttributeName, TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
[HtmlTargetElement("select", Attributes = ForAttributeName)]
[HtmlTargetElement("select", Attributes = ItemsAttributeName)]
[HtmlTargetElement("textarea", Attributes = ForAttributeName)]
public class CustomTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";
    private const string ItemsAttributeName = "asp-items";

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.Attributes.RemoveAll("id");
    }
}
```